# Can flutter project web application run into android studio emulator or flutter emulator

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

[image]

Hi, can flutter project web application be run in android studio mobile emulator or flutter emulator. I remember running video call testing from chrome to the mobile emulator since I only have one device. My only problem is when I run using the mobile emulator android studio or flutter emulator there will be an error that the dart package cannot be read when the emulator is run. I would like to ask your opinion. How do I resolve this issue? I have tried to run command flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080 --web-hostname 0.0.0.0 like this but the error package is still there. I have checked near the project structure module, there is an error in the dart package Library dart package has broken path.